# Element binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

```
<Button x:Name="btn_binding" Content="Binding" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="44" Margin="0,127,63,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txt_binding" Text="{Binding Content,ElementName=btn_binding}" Height="48" Margin="0,48,31,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="130"/>
```

it's result will be like this

[image]

Then i can get the same result by the below code

```
public partial class biding : Window
{
    public biding()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        txt_binding.Text=btn_binding.Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

please tell me what are  the differences of both and i want to which one is best to use...

Answer (score 2):

In first case you bind your `TextBox.Text` property to `Button.Content` property and it will be changed everytime the `Content` is changed. In second you just set `Text` property once in constructor and changing the `Button.Content` won't affect into it.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view... Xaml binding will be reflected in the designer at the time when you typed... No need to wait to run the solution to see the output..

In case of code behind .. you need to run the solution to see the results..